# What is Morgan smoking?

Tags: historical-accuracy, camelot

In the episode *The Battle of Bardon Pass* of the TV show *Camelot*, Morgan Pendragon is shown smoking a pipe:

[image]

What is she smoking? Since the show is taking place in Post-Roman Britain, it can't be tobacco (which comes from the Americas).

Comment: Note that most herbs that might be steeped as a tea can also be smoked. I myself have smoked California Poppy, Damiana, Hops, Mullein & Nettle. Having said that, I suspect that scene is mostly anachronistic. Unless it was specifically for a lung condition, historically the majority of herbs were steeped and drunk as a liquid.

Comment: I can think of a "herb" that is good to smoke ;)

Answer (score 2):

It can be a historical inaccuracy, but I found information on 'History of Smoking' Wikipedia page that cannabis and some other things were used in Ancient Greece.

> In Ancient Greece, smoke was used as healing practice and the Oracle of Delphi made prophecies while intoxicated by inhaling natural gases from a natural bore hole. The Greek historian Herodotos also wrote that the Scythians used cannabis for ritual mourning purposes and, to some degree, pleasure. He describes how Scythians burned hemp seed (IV, 75)

['History of Smoking' Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_smoking)

Comment: Yeah, but you're basically saying "It's not completely impossible it's cannabis." I was hoping for something more concrete.

Comment: @svick - The only other reasonable substance is opium. So what's the problem? ;p